# Handling errors for drive rest API in Android Java Application

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have implement a Drive Rest API successfully and everything seems to be working OK. What I'm confused about is handling errors if something goes wrong (loss of connection etc). I'm assuming these errors are common, so would there be a standard response I could add to my addOnFailureListener() or do I write code for all possible errors. What is the best practice to handle REST errors.

Main activity:

```
public void doRestore(int position){
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, getString(R.string.backup_restore_message), false, false);
    mDriveServiceHelper.restoreFile(data.get(position).getId()).
            addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {               
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(BackupNew.this, Splash.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    // What do I add here???
                }
            });
}
```

Helper class:

```
public Task<Void> restoreFile(final String fileId) {
    return Tasks.call(mExecutor, new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            InputStream is = mDriveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAsInputStream();
            FileOutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(context.getDatabasePath("appData"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            is.close();
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you assume errors are common? What is wrong with your current solution?  Best practice questions are normally off topic for SO you should try code review.

Comment: When I say "common" I mean the handling of the error would be similar.. eg. if the connection is lost or if credentials are wrong do this or do that. I've never dealt with REST API before and I'm not sure how to handle every single error. Or is it a simple case of letting the user know "something has gone wrong try again"

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the stacktrace message for debugging.
It seems the api is not returning any kind of message ,but as you know if it is in failure then you can show your own error message.